# How can I calculate a moving object speed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The goal is to show both transform and speed movement speed in text1 and text2.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Follow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform targetToFollow;
    public Text text;
    public Text text1;
    public Text text2;
    public float lookAtRotationSpeed;
    public float moveSpeed;

    private float minMoveSpeed = 0f;
    private Vector3 originPos;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        originPos = targetToFollow.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 lTargetDir = targetToFollow.position - transform.position;
        lTargetDir.y = 0.0f;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation,
            Quaternion.LookRotation(lTargetDir), Time.time * lookAtRotationSpeed);

        var distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetToFollow.position);

        text.text = "Transform Distance From Target " + distance.ToString();

        float ms = moveSpeed;

        if (distance > 5f)
        {
            ms = moveSpeed + 0.5f; //move faster
        }
        else if (distance < 1.5f)
        {
            ms = Mathf.Max(minMoveSpeed, ms - 0.3f); // move slower
        }
        else
        {
default value that equal moveSpeed here
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetToFollow.position, Time.deltaTime * ms);
        }

        if(distance < 0.5f && originPos == targetToFollow.position)
        {
            ms = 0f;
        }

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetToFollow.position, Time.deltaTime * ms);

        originPos = targetToFollow.position;
    }
}
```

Now I'm setting to text the transform distance from the target.
But I want to add now to text1 and text2 the speed movement of the transform and the target.
In the end there will be 3 texts ui's that will show the distance and movement speeds.

I tried like this for the target speed :

```
var speedPerSec = Vector3.Distance(originPos, targetToFollow.position) / Time.deltaTime;
text1.text = "Target Speed Per Second " + speedPerSec.ToString();
```

but when the target is moving the text of the speed the speedPerSec.toString() is blinking fast and not smooth like the distance in the first text.

maybe it's blinking because it's showing the speed a lot after the zero point like : 0.00656555 ?

Comment: When you hit the default movement case ("default value that equal moveSpeed here") you move your object twice. Once in the else clause, and another time 8 lines below. Just assign `ms` in the else clause and you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to track the speed of multiple objects (your transform and the target) the easiest way is to introduce a separate object handling the tracking and use an array of these.

```
[Serializable]
private class SpeedTracking
{
    public Transform trackedObject;
    public Text uiOutput;
    private Vector3 _position;
    private float _speed;

    public void Update(float elapsedTime, float changeThreshold)
    {
        Vector3 newPos = trackedObject.position;
        float newSpeed = Vector3.Distance(newPos, _position) / elapsedTime;

        if ((newSpeed == 0 && _speed != 0) || Mathf.Abs(newSpeed - _speed) > changeThreshold)
        {
            _speed = newSpeed;
            uiOutput.text = $"speed: {newSpeed:F3}";
        }
        _position = newPos;
    }
}

private const float SPEED_CHANGE_THRESHOLD = 0.001F;
[SerializeField]
private SpeedTracking[] _trackings;

void OnEnable()
{
    if (_trackings.Any(t => t.trackedObject == null || t.uiOutput == null))
    {
        Debug.LogError("at least one invalid tracking found");
        enabled = false;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    //[...]
    UpdateTrackings();
}

void UpdateTrackings()
{
    foreach (SpeedTracking tracking in _trackings)
    {
        tracking.Update(Time.deltaTime, SPEED_CHANGE_THRESHOLD);
    }
}
```

I also added a [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) to your output string (F3) showing only 3 decimal digits. (This alone would solve the flickering, but why update the ui more often than necessary?)

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks, yes `currentPos` was wrong. I also updated the answer to support the requested speed evaluation of multiple objects.

Comment: Thomas I tried your solution and first I tried it only for the target even if the target is standing still not moving at all it's showing speed. The speed is 2586.132 and it's changing all the time but stay in this range of value for the speed I made one item in the array and dragged the text1 to it with the target object. This is my code with your solution in the link.  https://pastebin.com/RmKfWfsR

Comment: If I remove this line transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetToFollow.position, Time.deltaTime * ms); and leave it only in the else the transform will not move at all when running the game.  The transform should move when running the game to the target

Comment: Try changing SpeedTracking to a class. (I updated the answer)

Comment: Do not remove the bottom movement line, but the one in the else clause.

Comment: Now the track speed is working if the object is not moving it's showing 0 for the speed but when moving the object the speed text is still blinking like before like the numbers of the speed change too fast to see.

Comment: Then simply adjust the threshold (e.g. `private const float SPEED_CHANGE_THRESHOLD = 0.1F;`). You can also replace the threshold with a field visible in inspector to test. The system only shows speed changes > threshold.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know how much velocity of object in specific time
you can do something like this.

```
public class VelocityDisplayer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform Object; // your target gameobject
    public Text View; // your text object
    private Vector3 _position; // last position of target

    private void OnEnable() {
        _position = Object.transform.position;
    }

    private void Update() {
        var dt = Time.deltaTime;
        var current = Object.transform.position;
        var delta = Vector3.Distance(current, _position);
        var velocity = delta / dt;
        View.text = (velocity).ToString("#,##0.000");

        // replace current position
        _position = current;
    }

}
```

but this show actual speed which depend on game world/physics of object not your setup movement speed variable

PS1. I prefer to use update because is UI scope

PS2. I prefer to split new class to track object